# Replace value in my Web.xml with maven

Tags: java, maven

I have in my Web.xml a value

```
<display-name> MyApp version @minorversion@- Pré prod </display-name>
```

I want to know if It’s possible to read a properties file with maven to replace the value in my Web.xml when I want to compile or package..?

Comment: to clarify: you want to read properties from a file and use its entries to replace tokens in another file, right?

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html Perhaps?

Comment: Yes It’s What I want do if It’s possible with maven

Answer (score 1):

1. Add src\main\resources\conf.properties:

   ```
   minorversion=1.0.0.0
   ```
2. pom.xml

   ```
          <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.4</version>
               <configuration>
                   <resourceEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</resourceEncoding>
                   <webResources>
                        <resource>
                             <filtering>true</filtering>
                             <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                             <includes>
                               <include>**/web.xml</include>
                             </includes>
                           </resource>
                   </webResources>
                   <filters>
                     <filter>src/main/resources/conf.properties</filter>
                   </filters>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
   ```
3. web.xml

   ```
   ...
   @minorversion@
   ```

   or

   ```
   ${minorversion}
   ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the maven-replacer-plugin

```
              <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>REPLACE</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>replace</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>{Phase to execute in}</phase>
                          <configuration>
                                <file>${Path to file to replace}</file>
                                <regex>true</regex>
                                <token>${Regex to match in file}</token>
                                <value>${New Value to Replace matched}</value>
                                <regexFlags>
                                    <regexFlag>MULTILINE</regexFlag>
                                    <regexFlag>DOTALL</regexFlag>
                                </regexFlags>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```